# How to convert the group by function to data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am new to scala and spark. I am trying group by through spark sql. When I am trying to save or to view the output.It throws following error.

```
value coalesce is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset
```

This is my code.

```
 val fp = filtertable.select($"_1", $"_2", $"_3",$"_4").groupBy("_1", "_2","_3")
 fp.show() // throws error
 fp.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").save("file://" + test.toString()) //throws error.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you have to perform an aggregate function after you use `groupBy`

Comment: But there is no necessity for me to aggregate.

Comment: What do you want to do with column "_4"?

Comment: In that case, can you explain how your input dataframe `fp` looks like and what do you want as the output?

Comment: what do you want to do after grouping ?

Comment: Do you just want all `distinct` values of _1, _2 and _3?

Comment: I'm new to scala too. What do the expressions $"_1",$"_2" mean?

Answer (score 3):

The question suggests that you want to write the grouped data in a text file in a csv format. If my analysis is correct, then *`groupBy` on `rdd` should be the solution you desire* **as `groupBy` on a `dataframe` would need `aggregation` to be followed**. So you will have to convert the `dataframe` to `rdd`, apply `groupBy` and finally write the output to the `csv` file as

```
val fp = df.select($"_1", $"_2", $"_3",$"_4")
      .rdd
      .groupBy(row => (row(0), row(1), row(2)))  // similar to groupBy("_1", "_2","_3") on dataframe
      .flatMap(kv => kv._2)   // taking the grouped data
      .map(_.mkString(","))   // making data in csv format

    fp.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("file://" + test.toString())
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to return the grouped items, then you can just select the first item of an ungrouped column and then to select on the grouped columns like so:

```
 val fp = filtertable
     .select($"_1", $"_2", $"_3", $"_4")
     .groupBy($"_1", $"_2", $"_3")
     .agg(first($"_4"))
     .select($"_1", $"_2", $"_3")
```

Comment: Which is a very long winded way of writing: `val fp = filtertable.select($"_1", $"_2", $"_3").distinct()`. ;)

Comment: Ahhh, was too focused on answering the question rather than offering a good solution!