# confused with spark groupBy

Tags: apache-spark

i'm rookie to scala & spark, i wanna filter some duplicated record with condition in hive table, i chose spark.

i'm familiar with kotlin, so i use kotlin to desc the logic:

```
data class Bean(val id: Int, val name: String, val time: String)

val data = listOf(
        Bean(1, "1", "20180101 00:00:00"),
        Bean(1, "2", "20180101 00:00:01"),
        Bean(2, "3", "20180101 00:00:02"),
        Bean(2, "4", "20180101 00:00:03"),
        Bean(3, "5", "20180101 00:00:04")
)

val result = data.groupBy { it.id }.map { (_, v) -> v.maxBy { it.time } }

result.forEach { println(it)}

//result

Bean(id=1, name=2, time=20180101 00:00:01)
Bean(id=2, name=4, time=20180101 00:00:03)
Bean(id=3, name=5, time=20180101 00:00:04)
```

there're many tables in hive with different columns, but all of them have 'id' & 'time', records may have the same id but different time, i just need the max time of the same id record.

```
spark.read.table(s"$dbName.$tableName")
    .groupBy($"id") // get a RelationalGroupedDataset
    ...
}
```

when i use groupBy, i get a RelationalGroupedDataset result, i wanna know how to do next? or may be it's a wrong step, how should i do?

Comment: just use .agg(max($"time")) after groupBy and you would need to import the spark functions.max

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert the group by fucnction to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164380/how-to-convert-the-group-by-fucnction-to-data-frame)

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan , use .agg(max($"time")) after groupBy, then the dataframe just have 2 columus- id & max("time"), i need the full record, just like my kotlin example

Comment: you should go with window function then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options there.

1). Make a struct, max it, then unpack it.

Structs are compared like tuples for max function, so time has to go as first field.

```scala
spark.read.table(s"$dbName.$tableName")
    .withColumn("v", struct($"time", $"name"))
    .groupBy($"id").agg(max($"v"))
    .select($"id", $"v.name", $"v.time")
```

2). Use window function and find first row for each entry.

I forget the exact syntax, but it's something like the following.

```scala
val w = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"time".desc)
spark.read.table(s"$dbName.$tableName")
    .withColumn($"num", row_number().over(w))
    .filter($"num" === 1)
```